# output depth must be evenly divisible by number of groups: 64 vs 3

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to make a CNN model in Python with Tensorflow Keras to train these images.
[bitwise images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssMIe.png)
This is how the images have been prepared for which worked, the code managed to find all the images:

```
training_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
  rescale = 1./255,
  horizontal_flip=True,
  vertical_flip=True,
  fill_mode='nearest')

train_generator = training_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=df_train_dominance,
        x_col="Filename",
        y_col="Dominance",
        target_size=(512, 512),
        class_mode='other')

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

val_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=df_test_dominance,
        x_col="Filename",
        y_col="Dominance",
        target_size=(512, 512),
        class_mode='other')
```

Then I try to make the following model:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', 
        input_shape=(512, 512, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(11, activation='softmax')
])

model.summary()
epoch_steps = 250
validation_steps = len(df_test_dominance)
model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
monitor = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, 
        patience=5, verbose=1, mode='auto',
        restore_best_weights=True)

start_time = time.time()
history = model.fit(train_generator,  
  verbose = 1, 
  validation_data=val_generator, callbacks=[monitor], epochs=25)
```

However, when I try to run this, I get the error "output depth must be evenly divisible by number of groups: 64 vs 3" So it won't allow me to make a convolutional layer with more than 3 filters. Why is this and what do I need to change to use more filters? The code does run fine with 3 filters.

I tried adding padding but that does not help. I also tried to invert the color of the images, but it also didn't solve the problem

Comment: fior some reason the param `group` in conv2d settings is not set to default=1, can you set it to 1 and check.

Comment: That indeed solved the problem, thank you!